# wlan0 isn't working most of times

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, ifconfig, airmon-ng

I earlier asked a question [Wifi isnt working after using wifite [duplicate]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/640890/wifi-isnt-working-after-using-wifite). [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/435060/449077) and [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/307784/449077) helped me. But, the problem is it works but, after few hours later when I start my laptop I get the same issue.

[image]

I faces the [issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/640890/wifi-isnt-working-after-using-wifite) whenever I run codes on the [image: picture]. Then, reboot my laptop everything works fine. I am unable to fix the issue permanently. I didn't use `wifite` after facing the [issue that moment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/640890/wifi-isnt-working-after-using-wifite)

```
sudo airmon-ng check kill
```

Output :
Killing these processes
PID Name
1394 wpa_supplicant

```
sudo service NetworkManager restart
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

Output : wlan0 : Error while getting interface flags : No such device

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 down
```

Output : wlan0: ERROR while getting interface flags:No such device

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

Output : wlan0 : ERROR while getting interface flags:No such device

```
sudo aireplay-ng wlan0
```

Output : Please specify an attack mode.
"aireplay-ng --help" for help

I was trying to set wlan0 up. But, there was no wlan0 when I run `ifconfig`. When I restarted after running those commands. wlan0 was working correctly but, I have faced the multiple times. After running wifite few days ago. Even I have faced the issue again now... I think `wifite` status is keep running or something else is happening to it.

```
iwconfig
```

> lo        no wireless extensions.
>
> eth0      no wireless extensions.
>
> wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any
> Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=15 dBm
> Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
> Power Management:off
>
> wwan0     no wireless extensions.
>
> docker0   no wireless extensions.

```
ifconfig
```

> docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
> inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
> ether 02:42:7d:19:b4:b6  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
> RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
> RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
> TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
> TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
>
> eth0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
> ether f0:de:f1:da:7d:80  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
> RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
> RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
> TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
> TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
> device interrupt 20  memory 0xf2500000-f2520000
>
> lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
> inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
> inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10
> loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
> RX packets 28  bytes 1728 (1.6 KiB)
> RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
> TX packets 28  bytes 1728 (1.6 KiB)
> TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

Comment: Please [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/22222). Instead, copy/paste the text into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format it as code. Your images aren't even legible unless we open in a new tab. Also, please tell us what the "issue" is so that we don't need to go and read some other question to understand this one.

Comment: @terdon Thanks for the information I have edited my question... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've already tried killing `wpa_supplicant` and restarting `NetworkManager`, but if the entire interface is no longer visible in the outputs of commands `iwconfig`, `ifconfig` `iw list` and/or `ip link show`, then that won't help.

The problem could be that the WiFi adapter driver has some kind of miscommunication with the hardware. It might be a suspend/hibernate issue, if you use that functionality.

You might want to check the `dmesg` output to see if there are any error messages related to the WiFi interface. And when the interface is no longer visible to commands like `iwconfig` etc., then you might try unloading & reloading the driver module for your WiFi interface.

When the `wlan0` interface is working correctly, `sudo ethtool -i wlan0 | awk '/driver:/{print $2;}'` should display the name of the driver module. Make a note of it.

When the `wlan0` goes missing again, run `sudo modprobe -r <driver module name>`, replacing `<driver module name>` with the actual module name you noted earlier, to unload the module. Then `sudo modprobe <driver module name>` to re-load it. This will force the driver to re-initialize the WiFi adapter 100% from scratch, hopefully clearing any miscommunication-related error states.

If this causes the WiFi adapter to start working again, and the problem seems to happen whenever you suspend your laptop, then you might need to customize the suspend/resume process to automatically shut down the WiFi adapter and unload its driver on suspend, and reload it on resume. This is generally doable fairly easily on most distributions, but I don't know what would be the recommended method for it for Kali specifically.

Apparently Kali is based on Debian, so putting the following script into `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/wifi-workaround.sh` and making it executable (`chmod a+rx /lib/systemd/system-sleep/wifi-workaround.sh`) might do the trick:

```
#!/bin/sh
# When suspending/resuming, systemd will call executables in /lib/systemd/system-sleep 
# with the following parameters:
# $1 = either "pre" or "post"
# $2 = "suspend", "hibernate", "hybrid-sleep" or "suspend-then-hibernate"
INTERFACE=wlan0
DRIVER_MODULE=<driver module name>    

case "$1" in
    pre)
        nmcli device disconnect $INTERFACE
        modprobe -r $DRIVER_MODULE
        ;;
    post)
        modprobe $DRIVER_MODULE
        nmcli device connect $INTERFACE
        ;;
esac

# Don't stop suspending/resuming even if we fail somehow.
exit 0
```

Disclaimer: I have not tested this at all, you might need to troubleshoot & adjust this yourself. But I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Maybe, it's been twice months I was looking for answer.. Finally, I got a beautiful answer. Thanks(Oh Sorry to use the Thanks word cause, there's a hovering message when we can `avoid comments like "+1" or "thanks"`.)

Comment: As you said, `It might be a suspend/hibernate issue`. But, sometimes I have to use suspend, So, How can I deal with it?

Comment: As you said, `It might be a suspend/hibernate issue`. But, sometimes I have to use suspend, So, How can I deal with it?

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: In the directory (`/lib/systemd/system-sleep/`) there's no file called `wifi-workaround.sh`. Should I create it? I have `sysstat.sleep`, `unattended-upgrades`, `hdparm`..

Comment: Yes, create it and copy in the contents I described.

Answer (score 0):

Run this script as sudo after resume:

```
#!/bin/bash
# program to check WiFi and reset if not running
  
#dns server 
IPTEST=1.1.1.1
  
iwconfig=/sbin/iwconfig
lspci=/usr/bin/lspci

#find 802 wireless device id
DEVICE=`$iwconfig 2>/dev/null | egrep 802 | awk ' {print $1}'`

#get PCI bus wireless #  
WLNUM=`$lspci | grep -i wireless | awk ' {print $1}'`
  
#get driver to unload
WLMOD=`$lspci -vv -s $WLNUM | grep -i "kernel driver" | awk ' {print $5}'`
  
  
#print out stats      
echo "IP is: $IPTEST"
echo "DEVICE is: $DEVICE"
echo "PCI DEV NUM is $WLNUM"
echo "PCI DRIVER is $WLMOD"
ping -c 1 $IPTEST

read -n 1 -p "Proceed ? " ANS

if [[ "$ANS" =~ [^yY] ]]; then 
    exit 0
fi
  
echo ""
if ping -c 1 $IPTEST >/dev/null 2>&1 ; 
then
    echo "$IPTEST 1 ok"
    exit 0
else
    echo "Ping failed"

    echo "stopping wifi "
    sudo nmcli radio wifi off
    echo "sleeping for 3..."
    sleep 3

    echo "unloading $DEVICE"
    sudo nmcli device disconnect $DEVICE
    echo "sleeping for 3..."
    sleep 3


    echo "unloading $WLMOD ..."
    sudo modprobe -r $WLMOD
    echo "sleeping for 3..."
    sleep 3

    echo "reloading $WLMOD"
    sudo modprobe $WLMOD
    echo "sleeping for 3..."
    sleep 3

    echo "reloading $DEVICE"
    sudo nmcli device connect $DEVICE
    echo "sleeping for 10..."
    sleep 10

    echo "stop wifi "
    sudo nmcli radio wifi off
    echo "sleeping for 3..."
    sleep 3
    
    echo "starting wifi"
    sudo nmcli radio wifi on
    echo "sleeping for 3..."
    sleep 5

    echo "test ping again ..."
    ping -c 1 $IPTEST
fi
exit 0
```

Comment: (1) Please explain what this script does and how it answers the question.  (2) If the script is run as root (sudo), you don’t need to have `sudo` commands *in* the script.  (3) Generic scripting advice: You should get into the habit of *always* quoting shell variables unless you have a reason not to.  Please use `$(…)` instead of `\`…\``.  And you don’t need to have a `;` at the end of a line.

Comment: 1: The script comments are self explanatory
2: True ... left in from when I was working out what to do step by step
3: Script etiquette: this was a quick and dirty solution to a long standing problem with Ubuntu, please feel free to edit and repost